# RSA Encryption and Decryption via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption, hash, cryptography, rsa

I am making a program that hashes the default data "2" into SHA256 algorithm then encrypting it to RSA then decrypting it then re convert it to string. My SHA256 has no problem but when it goes to the RSAEncrypt and RSADecrypt, both had same error of "Bad Length". What does it mean by bad length and why does it happen specially on a hashed data of "2"? Also I have RSA parameters of Private Key 11, Public Key 5, Modulus 14. Anyone, got any advice for this? Appreciate those who'll give me assistance.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Module Program

Sub Main()
    Dim m_privkey_tx As String = "11"
    Dim m_pubkey_tx As String = "5"
    Dim m_mod_tx As String = "14"
    Dim m_message_tx As String = "2"
    Dim m_hash_tx As Byte()
    Dim oSHA256 As SHA256 = SHA256.Create

    m_hash_tx = oSHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_message_tx))
    Console.WriteLine("SHA256: " & Convert.ToBase64String(m_hash_tx))

    Dim params As RSAParameters = New RSAParameters()

    params.Exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_pubkey_tx)
    params.D = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_privkey_tx)
    params.Modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_mod_tx)

    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(RSAEncrypt(m_hash_tx, params, False)))
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(RSADecrypt(m_hash_tx, params, False)))
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Public Function RSADecrypt(ByVal DataToDecrypt() As Byte, ByVal RSAKeyInfo As RSAParameters, ByVal m_oeap_yn As Boolean) As Byte()
    Try
        Dim m_dec_bit() As Byte

        Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)
            m_dec_bit = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, m_oeap_yn)
        End Using

        Return m_dec_bit

    Catch ex As CryptographicException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message())
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Function RSAEncrypt(ByVal DataToEncrypt() As Byte, ByVal RSAKeyInfo As RSAParameters, ByVal m_oeap_yn As Boolean) As Byte()
    Try
        Dim m_enc_bit() As Byte

        Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)
            m_enc_bit = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, m_oeap_yn)
        End Using

        Return m_enc_bit

    Catch ex As CryptographicException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message())
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: RSA can only encrypt messages that are smaller than the modulus (minus space required by padding). SHA256 is 32 bytes in size. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding needs 11 bytes. Your modulus 14 is only 4 bits so not even one byte. Apart from that the modulus must have a minimum size for security reasons, today >= 2048 bits. E.g. your key can be cracked immediately (14 = 2 * 7).